# Replacing root relative links with full URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a plugin that will be used multiple times in a single page.  Each is contained in a div with a unique id.

The content of the divs will be received with images whose paths need to be prepended with different domains. Eg

```
<div id="mydiv"><img src="/images/somepic.jpg"></div>
```

My current function does locate the images correctly and modify them:

```
jQuery("#mydiv img[src^='/']" ).prop('src',
  function( _idx, oldHref ) {
    return 'http://example.com'+oldHref;
  }
);
```

However it sets their src to http://example.comhttp://thecurrentsite/images/somepic.jpg even though the source started with / and did not contain thecurrentsite.

How is thecurrentsite URL getting into the oldHref passed by prop()?

Comment: What does `jQuery(this).attr('src')` return?

Comment: @rybo111 that solves it!  Add as an answer?  `return 'http://example.com'+jQuery(this).attr('src');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prop returns the src as a full path
use attr instead to get the original path

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnu04gqt/), it alerts the two versions:

```
<img src='test.html'>

$("img").prop("src") => full path
$("img").attr("src") => original relative path
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `attr` instead of `prop`, it works. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee3arp6v/)**